# What does this excel formula using the keyword "table" mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In an excel sheet cell, I see the following formula which outputs a number (formatted as a percentage) based upon two numbers in K5 and K12:

```
{=TABLE(K5,K12)}
```

But I can't find the "TABLE" keyword in the help and I do not understand what the outer braces mean either.

Answer (score 2):

- Possibly you are confused with the word TABLE, let me say the formula `{=TABLE(K5,K12)}` reflects the Two Variable Table, where K5 is Row Input cell & K12 is Column Input Cell, user can create by using `DATA` tab then `What If Analysis`.
- Excel uses TABLE as reserve word whenever user execute either One or Two variable table.
- Excel has one more command,  is `INSERT` menu then `TABLE`, but that Table is a user created data in Tabular form called Table, and this is different then the One or Two variable tables.

***Because it's difficult to cover all aspects in one post, therefore for better understanding I would like to refer** [following link.](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/10/24/data-table-excel-one-variable-two-variable/) , **help you to understand the mechanism of the One/Two variable TABLE.***